# What's the method resolution order with pyqt classes?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, method-resolution-order

I was recently asked about an issue in pyqt inheritance, here is the problem: Assuming I have class A with a method `closeEvent(event)`, and a class B inheriting A and QMainWindow (and so having a `closeEvent(event)` method). What will be the resolution order for `closeEvent`? Considering the python documentation, this would depend on the inheritance order. However following example shows that's not the case... Does any one can help?
I'm using Python3.6.2 on windows with PyQt5.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
import sys

class A():
    def closeEvent(self,event):
        print("A")

class B(QMainWindow):
    def closeEvent(self,event):
        print("B")
        super().closeEvent(event)

class C(A,B):
    pass

class D(B,A):
    pass

class E(QMainWindow,A):
    pass

class F(A,QMainWindow):
    pass

def test(TestClass, msg):
    """Create class instance and show it. Click on cross to close."""
    print(msg)
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    test = TestClass()
    test.show()
    app.exec()

test(C,"C(A,B)?") #           >>> A
test(D,"D(B,A)?") #           >>> B
test(E,"E(QMainWindow,A)?") # >>> A ??? Why ???
test(F,"F(A,QMainWindow)?") # >>> A
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a really complex issue, which involves differences between Python and C++ when it comes to how cooperative multi-inheritance works. So the answer I am going to give here is more in the way of a brief overview. I think a full treatment may be unfeasible for a single SO answer.

Part of the problem lies in how PyQt determines what class it should inherit from. This can be illustrated by comparing the values of the `__base__` attribute for a pure Python *vs* a PyQt version of your class hierarchy:

```
class A: pass
class B(QMainWindow): pass
class C(A, B): pass
class D(B, A): pass
class E(QMainWindow, A): pass
class F(A, QMainWindow): pass

print('pyqt:')
print('C:', C.__base__)
print('D:', D.__base__)
print('E:', E.__base__)
print('F:', F.__base__)

class M: pass
class A: pass
class B(M): pass
class C(A, B): pass
class D(B, A): pass
class E(M, A): pass
class F(A, M): pass

print('python:')
print('C:', C.__base__)
print('D:', D.__base__)
print('E:', E.__base__)
print('F:', F.__base__)
```

Output:

```
pyqt:
C: <class '__main__.B'>
D: <class '__main__.B'>
E: <class 'PyQt5.QtWidgets.QMainWindow'>
F: <class 'PyQt5.QtWidgets.QMainWindow'>
python:
C: <class '__main__.A'>
D: <class '__main__.B'>
E: <class '__main__.M'>
F: <class '__main__.A'>
```

This is not a bug. The differences here are entirely due to implementation details, which I am not going to attempt to explain (even if I could). It is very likely that PyQt *could* change its implementation to be more closely aligned to the Python behaviour. But it has instead chosen to compromise and not move too far away from how things work in Qt/C++. I would guess that this decision was influenced by backwards-compatibility issues and perhaps also the ease of maintaining the code-base. Probably you would have to ask the author of PyQt if you wanted to get a definitive answer on this point.

Another (much bigger) part of the problem lies in how to get cooperative multi-inheritance to work when some classes in the hierarchy are inherently uncooperative (e.g. because they are written in C++, like Qt is). I think it may be possible to solve such problems to some extent - PyQt has at least done this for class construction (see [Support for Cooperative Multi-inheritance](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/multiinheritance.html)). But doing it in general for a large library like Qt is obviously a much larger task. I suppose there will always be some wrinkles (like the one you discovered) that are never fully ironed out.

Comment: Thanks for these informations. I suspected something like that, but that's a pity PyQt's documentation does not mention it, or at least give an example. By the way, I usually advise to not use multiple inheritance...